# Лучшие практики создания API и документирования

Tags: api, rest, swagger, json-rpc, openapi

**REST** и **json-rpc** имеют, как кажется, явные недостатки. На многочисленных примерах в вакууме, которые не имеют отношения к реалиям, REST кажется отличным решением.

По REST каждый URL это ресурс и него есть HTTP статусы, на основе которых клиент (приложение) может определять свое поведение. Например, все есть: комментрии - `/comment` , статьи - `/post`, профили - `/user` и т.д. И это легко поддается документирования сваггером.

---

Но в реальной жизни эндпоинты это чаще всего какие-то действия с бизнес логикой, множеством моделей за раз и сайд эффектами. И апи превращается во что-то среднее между RPC и REST -- Имеем ресурсы и какие-то действия.
Например, что есть: регистрация, подтверждение телефона, оплата услуги и т.д? Подтверждение телефона или подписание договора с оплатой сложно назвать ресурсом, как быть в таком случае? Тут скорее пользователь совершает действия над множеством ресурсов.

Клиент (приложение), согласно REST, должен знать айди ресурса, над которым мы манипулируем, что обязывает приложение знать какую-то часть бизнес логики, для того чтобы правильно этим манипулировать. Ведь ресурс это скорее модель. А даже под капотом мы не работаем лишь с одними моделями. Что приводит к натягиванию одной парадигмы на другую.

Не говоря уже о том, что невозможно описать все возможные ошибки HTTP кодами. Например, есть у нас ошибка `403 - Forbidden`. 
Код уже кем-то использован? Ну, вроде условно это `Forbidden`. Код не использован, но уже истек? Ну, вроде тоже `Forbidden`. Код не истек и не аннулирован, но он вовсе не от этого ресурса? Тоже, казалось бы, `Forbidden`. Ну или быть может `404` с точки зрения REST. Но как тогда понять это смс-код `404` или сам ресурс, для которого он применяется? Клиент должен как-то обрабатывать это и реагировать.
Из чего вытекает вторая проблема: Swagger не позволяет нам описывать на один HTTP код разные ошибки.

Почему тогда не использовать RPC? Причины тоже есть. Явный плюс, который я вижу, это отвязывание мышления от парадигмы HTTP протокола и ресурсов. Но, кажется, это не супер распространенная технология и там тоже есть не все ответы на вопросы среди сообществ.

Из чего вытекает вообще вопрос - какие есть best practices? Или то, что вам удалось применить в реальной жизни и это не превратилось через пару месяцев в монструозную кашу и несколько слоев абстракции над абстракциями?

Comment: Ну вы можете попробовать GraphQL, но это тоже не серебряная пуля. Ещё есть такая вещь, как WSDL

Comment: @ArchDemon там тоже скорее больше вопросов чем ответом. В статьях на хабре в комментариях километровые холивары. Опять же остается вопрос, как это правильно документировать и не решать месяцами проблемы самой технологии.

Comment: Ни одно из решений не является универсальным. Вам придётся сделать выбор, основываясь на ваших критериях. Я обновил первый комментарий, но советовать XML в век JSON, на мой взгляд, тоже сомнительно :)